# Creating a C++ program to solve an equation of motion using Euler's method

Tags: c++, differential-equations

I am trying to compute the time history of the velocity described by the equation: 
**dV/dt = g − (C_d/m) * V^2**. g = 9.81, m = 1.0, and C_d = 1.5.
To do this I need to create a program in c++ that uses the Euler explicit method to numerically solve the equation. I am trying to find the velocity from t = 0 to t = 1 seconds with three different step sizes of delta_t = 0.05, 0.1, and 0.2 seconds. And then you are supposed to show your percent error to the analytical solution given as: **V(t) = sqrt((m*g)/C_d) * tanh(sqrt((g*C_d)/m) * t).** 
My problem is I am not sure how to iterate through Euler's method multiple times with different time intervals. So far I have solved the analytical equation, but am unsure where to go from here. If anyone could help point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

````
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    double m = 1.0;     // units in [kg] 
    double g = 9.81;    // units in [m/s^2]
    double C_d = 1.5;   // units in [kg/m]  
    double t;           // units in [s]
    double v;           // units in [m/s]


    cout << "The velocity will be examined from the time t = 0 to t = 1 seconds." << endl;
    cout << "Please select either 0.05, 0.1, or 0.2 to be the time interval:" << endl;
    cin >> t;
    cout << "You have chosen the time interval of: " << t << " seconds." << endl;


    v = sqrt((m * g) / C_d) * tanh(sqrt((g * C_d) / m) * t);

    cout << "The velecity at a time of "<< t << " seconds is equal to: " << v << " m/s." << endl;


    return 0;

} ```
````

Comment: *My problem is I am not sure how to iterate through Euler's method multiple times with different time intervals. So far I have solved the analytical equation*  This is what functions are for.  Write a function that take the variables you need and then call it multiple times with the different parameter(s).

Comment: @NathanOliver Should I do this outside or inside of my int main()?

Comment: The function needs to be defined outside of `main`.

Comment: @NathanOliver ok that's what I thought. Would I be correct in assuming that the way I need to iterate through the equation would be through if statements?

Comment: I would store the results in an array and then you can use a for loop to visit each result and display it's variance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over *t* with increments of *A*, calculating the result of the formula with each *t*, you would write a for loop.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double m = 1.0;     // units in [kg] 
    double g = 9.81;    // units in [m/s^2]
    double C_d = 1.5;   // units in [kg/m]

    std::cout << "The velocity will be examined from the time t = 0 to t = 1 seconds." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Please select the time interval:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1: 0.05" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2: 0.1" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3: 0.2" << std::endl;

    double A = 0; // increment in for loop
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    switch (x) { // check what the input is equal to
        case 1: A = 0.05; break;
        case 2: A = 0.1; break;
        case 3: A = 0.2; break;
        default: std::cout << "Unknown option!" << std::endl; return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "You have chosen the time interval of: " << A << " seconds." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Results of V(t):" << std::endl;
    // this initializes a variable t as 0, 
    //and while t is lower than or equal to 1, 
    //it will increment it by a and execute the logic within the scope of the loop.
    for (double t = 0; t < (1 + A); t += A) {
        std::cout << "at t = " << t << ": " << sqrt((m*g) / C_d) * tanh(sqrt((g*C_d) / m) * t) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Refer to https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-for-loop/ for more information. Note: I've also introduced a switch statement into the code to prevent unknown values from being input. https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-switch-case/